# Is there an equivalent of Linux's "nmcli con add" on Windows or macOS?

Tags: windows, networking, macos

I need to configure a custom connection to a device. Is there a command utility on Windows/macOS that does what [`nmcli`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmcli) (Network Manager CLI) does on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows I suppose the equivalent is
[Network Shell (Netsh)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh):

> Network shell (netsh) is a command-line utility that allows you to configure and display the status of various network communications server roles and components after they are installed on computers running Windows Server.

Although the documentation says "Windows Server", it works in all Windows
versions.

See also
[Netsh Command Syntax, Contexts, and Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts).